# maven-jar-plugin with maven-source-plugin not working

Tags: java, maven, maven-plugin, maven-jar-plugin, maven-source-plugin

I'm using `maven-jar-plugin` to create JAR with my test class as below:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-jar-plugin.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

I want to add source code to test JAR using `maven-source-plugin` like that:

```
    <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven-source.version}</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <id>attach-sources</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
            <execution>
                <id>attach-test-sources</id>
                <goals>
                    <goal>test-jar</goal>
                </goals>
            </execution>
        </executions>
    </plugin>
```

As results I got four JAR files:

```
<name>.jar
<name>-sources.jar
<name>-tests.jar
<name>-test-sources.jar
```

My question is what I do wrong that I can't download sources for test's classes but can do that for main classes?

Regards

Comment: See the answer of Gerold Broser. He is correct...

Comment: Ok I agree, but still I'm looking for any solver for my case.

Comment: What exactly is not working? You have got both the tests and the appropriate sources packages?

Comment: Yes, I have got tests.jar and test-source.jar, but other project in Intelij where I used them does not see this source jar for test's classes.
For main classes I can download the sources but not for tests with that solution. My question is what I do wrong that I can't download sources for test's classes?

Answer (score 1):

`<name>-tests.jar` is not a misspelling, see [Apache Maven JAR Plugin / jar:test-jar](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-jar-plugin/test-jar-mojo.html):

> `<classifier>`   Classifier to used for `test-jar`. **Default value is:** `tests`.